# how jade with nodejs use inline js "return confirm('are you delete it !!')"

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

i use nodejs with jade 
somewhere i use a tag or button tag

button tag like

```
button.btn.btn-danger.del(type="button", data-id="#{item._id}" onclick="return confirm('delete now?');") delete
```

a tag like

```
a(href="#" onclick="return confirm('delete now?');") delete
```

but when i click delete button then the pop window ask me choose "NO" or "YES"
it always return YES

when i click delete a tag then the pop window ask me choose "NO" or "YES"
it always return NO

i confused by the jade template ? how the "return confirm" could be right way to use?

Comment: How do you check what was returned on click?

Comment: always return false or always return true

Comment: I meant how do you verify whether it is returning `true` or `false`?